# GTMHTTPFetcher.m 'initWithRequest:delegate:start Immediately:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use NSURLSession (see NSURLSession.h)

Tags: ios, gmail-api, xcode7

I am getting the above error when I import **GTL.xcodeproj** of Gmail API and run it. I am using Xcode 7.1 beta and many errors our coming of deprecated methods in the header files of Gmail API binary. How should I correct it?

Comment: Since it is deprecated you can still use it. I suggest you to wait for the library update.

Comment: Ok thanks @MarcoPace

Comment: @AdityaBorde hii facing same issue..plz post answer if you get any solution for this

Comment: @Niks if you want to use Gmail API in iOS you will have to either use iOS 8.4 sdk to build or you have to wait for library to update. I am trying the first option currently

Comment: @AdityaBorde okay bro..thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it this way:

in your IOS project, click on your embedded GTL.xcodeproject, choose the info tab, change your "IOS Deployment target" to 8.4.

I also had to comment out #define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 1 in GTLService.h to get the API to compile successfully.

Once I did that it compiled and runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Goto GTMHTTPFetcher.m and add below code in @interface GTMHTTPFetcher (GTMHTTPFetcherLoggingInternal)

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
         delegate:(id)delegate
 startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately;
```